# what the difference between manifest scope/start_url and ServiceWorkerModule.register scope?

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm touching the pwa in angular 11 . When implementing , I noticed that there are two scope defination in pwa :

1. in manifest.webmanifest , scope and start_url to define what scope the ngsw-worker.js should handle

   {
   ...
   "scope": "./",
   "start_url": "./",
2. in app.module.ts , another scope

   ServiceWorkerModule.register("ngsw-worker.js", {
   enabled: environment.production,
   ***scope***: "./xxxxx/",
   registrationStrategy: "registerImmediately",
   })

Could anyone tell me what the difference among them ? quite confused which one to set as what.

My application is a spa but deployed at a subdomain as /xxxxx/ so, in this case , How should I set?